# I have written a method that returns otp from email , but everytime I run it it returns the 2nd latest otp not the latest one

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, one-time-password

I have written a method that returns otp from email , but everytime I run it it returns the 2nd latest otp not the latest one. When I empty the inbox so that there are no emails of the same sender, so the method does not get confused, it tells that no otp found despite the email being there.

I tried in debugging mode the method gets executed successfully,but when run without debugging it fails.

I have tried multiple methods of differentiating based on sender and subject etc , but same result.

This is the code:

```
public void getEmailOTP() throws MessagingException, IOException, InterruptedException, NoSuchProviderException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
    Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "dummy@email.com", "dummypassword");

    Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
    Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();
    Message latestMessage = messages[messages.length-1];

    String content = latestMessage.getContent().toString();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("code is:  <b>(\\d{4}+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        String otp = matcher.group(1);
        enterOTP(otp);
        clickContinueButton();
        openHamburgerMenu2();
    } else {
        System.out.println("No OTP found");
    }
}
```